# mysql slow log path: successful on main disk, failed on a mounted disk

Tags: mysql, logging, disk

All

I am on a Ubuntu box with mysql 5.5.
I want to enable the mysql's slow log, and I have made it working and logging very well if I set

log_slow_queries = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log

And I also noticed If I set

log_slow_queries = /any/path/on/a_mounted_disk/log

It will fail.

I have double checked so /any/path/on/a_mounted_disk/log do exist and writable by everyone (0777, just to test).

And what is more, if I use

mysql> SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'ON';

The mysql is telling me that File "/any/path/on/a_mounted_disk/log" cannot be found but it is actually there.

So my question is:  Is it true that mysql's slow log cannot be recorded on a mounted disk? Or even mysql cannot visit any file on a mounted disk?

Since the primary disk is very small, Is there anyway to put the slow log on a mounted disk?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: is /any/path/on/a_mounted_disk/log a directory. If so you must add something like this. "/file.log"

Comment: @BerndBuffen, i mean, it is a file, not a path